# development boards and open source environment

Tags: ide, arm, microcontroller

I am an intern , I am working on an embedded project which has got a micro controller with ARM processor and a gps receiver, we have developed our application on stm32f10XX  development board from olimex  and the Development environment, we used is olimex open ocd!! we have tested our application every thing works well, now we want to go for production,design our own prototype board by specifying our requirements ports and pcb design, and now comes the question which is, **how to test our application on the new board**? is there any open source development environment which we can go for?

Comment: Could you elaborate on what you're expecting in a 'development environment'?  Are you running any kind of operating system on it?

Comment: development environment , I mean development tools like code composer studios, keil development studios etc (for arm development)

Answer (score 0):

IAR have a code size limited evaluatioin package which you can find [here](http://supp.iar.com/Download/SW/?item=EWARM-EVAL)

I'm not entirely sure of your requirements but the evaluation has a 32kb code size limit (16kb for arm M0/M1) which can actually go a very long way.You will however need a JTAG programmer 
If you don't already have something suitable then this [JLink](http://www.segger.com/jlink.html) USB JTAG emulator is what you need (it works with most embedded IDE's)

Comment: I am right now using the 30 days trail of IAR work bench ,our Code is around 0.5 mb it is a good amount of code actually, is there any other way of going for production with out purchasing a license?

Comment: I see. Well in that case you can try this with ARM GNU compiler: http://www.bipom.com/products/us/319589.html although I'm not too familar with it or if it even will fit your requirements

Comment: the main problem for us is we need an Development tool open source irrespective of the development boards. in my research i just came through only one development tool which is IAR workbench for arm and the remaining development environments need firmware libraries of the board that we are deploying our code inn and since ours is a test board that we just designed, we are unable to move forward!!

Comment: gnu tools are easy to come by and easy to use.  (codesourcery now mentor graphics, lite is a good start or roll your own).   what libraries are you talking about?  for your own peripherals?  I would assume you have to write your own libraries for your own peripherals?

Comment: Writing code for your own hardware shouldn't be a problem. Most likely you can modify the code you have for your development board and change the low level code or HAL.

Comment: Why are you baulking at the cost of an IAR licence.  They do a version that is just for the Cortex-M family that costs the same as an engineer would cost for less than a week's work.  If you are already porting to/using the IAR tools then it really makes no sense to spend much effort going to a "free" compiler.  There are always costs involved in going that route.  You have to support the compiler yourself or go to another vendor (Rowley/Atollic/...) who configure/integrate the compiler into a programming/debugging environment.